# How to pit viper pits maintain high sensitivity across a wide temperature range?

Tags: temperature, senses

Pit viper infrared vision works nothing like our photochemical rods and cones. It would be blinded by its own thermal noise it if did. Instead, they are sensitive to changes of temperature [of only 3mk][1] across a wide range of body temperatures (17C to 37C for the poikilotherm snakes).

How do the cells detect tiny changes in temperature but be insensitive to slower but 1000-fold larger temperature changes?

[1]: [https://journals.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/ajpcell.00040.2004#:~:text=Multiple%2D%20and%20single%2Dunit%20neuronal,15%E2%80%9337%C2%B0C](https://journals.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/ajpcell.00040.2004#:%7E:text=Multiple%2D%20and%20single%2Dunit%20neuronal,15%E2%80%9337%C2%B0C)).